# Images Won't Load But Path Is Right?

Tags: php, html, image

I've been working on my server for several days and I'm having major issues with server includes and images. I removed all of the PHP Includes but I would like to add them back. The other issue I'm having is with images. I've added the full path domain and all and it's still not loading the image. If you take the URL path of the image and place it in the browser, it works. I've cleared caches and cookies several times and still coming up with no solution.

Comment: `/assets/images/cocrele.png`

Comment: what kind of help are you expecting? you've no code posted and especially for the php tag.

Comment: This is **way** too broad of an issue. How can we possibly have the answer to something like that?

Comment: add any query string param to ur /assets/images/cocrele.png?date=123

Comment: Looks like the server is responding with a `403 Forbidden` when there's a referer from the page?

Comment: @Brett Melton r u  using any framework??

Comment: My apologies for not supplying the proper code. I added an htaccess file and it solved the issue. I kept seeing a 403 forbidden but couldn't find out anything. Thanks for all your help and support. ~Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers says that the image loading was forbidden:

"A 403 Forbidden error means that you do not have permission to view the requested file or resource. While sometimes the website owner does this intentionally, other times it is due to misconfigured permissions or an improper .htaccess file. "

Comment: This reply helped me the most! I checked a few htaccess files on my server and couldn't find anything too big. I added an htaccess file to the root folder and now my images are showing :) Thanks for pointing me in the right directions! ~Brett

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that the images in CSS need to be relative to the path from style.css

So for instance, if you have the following folders:

```
   index.php
   img
     img.jpg
   css
     style.css
```

If you are putting the image "img.jpg" in the "style.css", the path will be:

```
  "../img/img.jpg"
```

While if you are putting images directly in your index.php the path will be:

```
 "img/img.jpg"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't help but I appreciate the general tips. Thanks J. ~Brett